# Track advertisement earnings per blog post and page in wordpress?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, adsense, ads

I have this unique situation (though i doubt it no one has ever asked this before!). I want to track advertisement earnings from a service like Adsense per blog post and per page or per author .

Why i want to achieve this ? we are quite a few number number of authors in this new website we are launching .In order to answer any future discrepences that might occur and effective profit sharing.

If its not possible with adsense is there any decent enough alternate offers this feature please suggest?

Alternatively is there any tracking plugin or some service like google analytics that can be of help?

if possible is there any way to export this data also?

Comment: I guess you have to group the earing in Adsense, ie. you have to use parameters matching their API.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that.i have a little experience with API's. i Tried googling again about analytics and their API but with little progress.THanks By the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics offers this feature and pretty much the way you wanted it.

In GA, in the Content Section, check the AdSense subsection ... specifically the AdSense Pages report. It tells you page wise which content has generated how much revenues.

And yes, these reports are exportable in CSV format which open in Excel.

If I were you, I would put the posts and authors in one worksheet, the AdSense Pages report in another and do a vlookup in Excel for finding out the author-wise AdSense earnings.

Comment: thank you for the answer and its exactly the way i want it to work . Ill give it a go :) once again thanks a lot !

Comment: I also need this exactly. But where is the AdSense subsection  in analytics ? I couldnt find that

Comment: @SVinesh In Behavior > Publisher